# Is it possible to use mat-select and mat-chips together?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I wanna know if it's possible have a "mix" of `mat-select` and `mat-chip-list`. In the `chip-list`, I want to show the selected options from `mat-select`.

If it is, how can I do it?

Comment: It's always possible, it's just not natively supported so you'll have to change a lot of things and face a lot of CSS errors. Consider doing your own component instead.

Comment: You also have [this](https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=app%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.ts) which isn't exactly what you asked, but serves the same purpose.

Comment: cannot get the link. Error @Maryannah

Comment: Stange, it's the "Chips autocomplete" from the [Material examples](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to use `<mat-select-trigger>` within `<mat-select>`. Inside `<mat-select-trigger>` place `<mat-chip-list>`.

In your HTML template you need something like:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppingsControl" multiple>

    <mat-select-trigger>
      <mat-chip-list>
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let topping of toppingsControl.value"
          [removable]="true" (removed)="onToppingRemoved(topping)">
          {{ topping }}
          <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
      </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-select-trigger>

    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>

  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<br/> <!-- only for debug -->
{{ toppingsControl.value | json }}
```

And in your `ts`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'select-multiple-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-multiple-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-multiple-example.css'],
})
export class SelectMultipleExample {
  toppingsControl = new FormControl([]);
  toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];

  onToppingRemoved(topping: string) {
    const toppings = this.toppingsControl.value as string[];
    this.removeFirst(toppings, topping);
    this.toppingsControl.setValue(toppings); // To trigger change detection
  }

  private removeFirst<T>(array: T[], toRemove: T): void {
    const index = array.indexOf(toRemove);
    if (index !== -1) {
      array.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

}
```

[Here is a complete example with Angular Material 9, but it works the same in version 6.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v9-mat-select-with-mat-chip-list?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.html)

I hope this helps!

[image: Demo]

Comment: I copied your code but in my project the option doesn't get deselected when the chip is removed. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: @SvenCazier, please share a stackblitz to see if I can help you.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v10-mat-select-with-mat-chip-list-qx5cq6

The difference is I'm using Angular Material version 10...

Comment: I got back to it and did a bit of testing. Just clearing the list works, and for some reason changing the list works fine when it's bound to a button ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. So the easiest workaround I found is to clear the list first and then setting the new values. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v10-mat-select-with-mat-chip-list-v2-qx5cq-8c3?file=src/app/select-multiple-example.ts

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I needed to make one change to get it working though. Where you set `this.toppingsControl.setValue(toppings);`, I needed to create a new array to update the mat-select (old values were still selected when opening mat-select) like `this.toppingsControl.setValue([...toppings]);`. Using Angular 10 and Material 10.

Comment: how do you make it required?

Comment: Do you know why it breaks with Angular / Material 13? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v9-mat-select-with-mat-chip-list-lnss9e.

Comment: @SimoneBracaloni - https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24796

Comment: This worked great just implemented it in my angular 15 project. Need to  change <mat-chip-list> to <mat-chip-listbox> to get it to work.

Answer (score 7):

To fix the issue with the wrong display of the chip list with Material 13 i added this to my css

```
.mat-select-trigger {
   height: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: Becomes redundant with Material 15 (at least for me).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by pushing the selected values to a variable and read this variable in the mat-chip-list.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected" multiple>
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip *ngFor="let value of selected">{{value}}</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

TS:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-example',
  templateUrl: 'my-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['my-example.css'],
})
export class MyExample {
  selected: string[] = [];
}
```

Comment: That's not really what I wanted, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you want to show your selected values as mat-chips in your select instead sepperated by comma?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I want

Answer (score 0):

you can find another variation of your requirement in below stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v10-mat-select-with-mat-chip-list-qx5cq-jzc1mi?file=src/app/select-multiple-example.html

Answer (score 0):

[MhagnumDw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60168206/10853425) [broke](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24796) since Material V13, can be fixed with the following CSS.

```
.mat-select-trigger{
   height: fit-content;
}

.mat-select-arrow-wrapper{
   align-self: start;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v9-mat-select-with-mat-chip-list-ufwxke?file=src%2Fstyles.scss%3AL16

Credit https://stackoverflow.com/a/72515815/10853425

Answer (score 0):

Just updating with an example from Angular 17, things seem to work fine without custom styles.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nucddw?file=src%2Fexample%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts,src%2Fexample%2Fselect-multiple-example.html