# Add styles for each mat-option elements in mat-select module after selecting the option

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I need to add styles for each of the mat-option elements dynamically after selecting the values in mat-select module.Below is the code that I've used to add list of permissions

**permissions.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field class="input-permissions">
        <mat-select placeholder="Permissions" multiple>
          <mat-option
            *ngFor="let permission of permissions"
            [value]="permission.id"
          >
            {{ permission.appPermissions }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```

This is how I want,

[image: Example]

This is how I'm getting now ,

[image: Example2]

I've tried to add styles by using inspect feature in browser but the selected values are present inside one span class and hence it would add styles to the whole field itself.

Comment: This material component adjusts more to what you want https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples

Comment: can this be implemented in mat-select?

Comment: Thanks @JuanPabloMorenoMartín for the help. This works very well for me.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58282436/is-it-possible-to-use-mat-select-and-mat-chips-together. I've found this article helpful for me.